# Why does some compound as given in the image below change from low spin to high spin above a particular transition temperature?

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, magnetism, crystal-field-theory

[image]

Magnetic moment sudden increase at a particular temperature is explained by CFT. But why does it happen at all?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetochemistry#Paramagnetism